# Is there a way to see the CDN server location which served my request?

Tags: networking, firefox, cdn

I'm interested to see which particular CDN server was used to serve my request(to see how close it's to me).

I checked my networking tab([needed to load the request without caching to see the IP address](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1154632)) and I saw the following:
[image]

Then, I tried to use IP find tool and my results were the following:
[image]

Can it be true that the CDN server which served my request was in the U.S. given that I'm located in Ukraine? Stack Exchange sites have very good load time and I'm trying to understand the CDN part in all this.

Comment: The CDN in question most likely uses [Anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `traceroute`, `tracert`, or `mtr` tools – directly from your computer, **not** from a website – and look at the last few hops in the trace report. As many carriers give descriptive names to their routers, that will give you a hint about their physical location.

Additionally, the round-trip time (ms) reported by traceroute & ping will give you a hint about the physical distance.

(Many CDNs use anycast, meaning that the same IP address can physically exist in many different locations – most GeoIP databases and websites have absolutely no clue how to deal with those, and just report the address where the company itself was registered.

Even without anycast usage, many networks are physically spread out across whole countries or continents, and only the network owner itself can truly know which host is where. Also, many companies have a single large IP address range in the WHOIS database but actually announce smaller sub-ranges from different locations.)

Comment: As you have an IP or two (at the end of e.g. `mtr` output) check https://www.ultratools.com/tools/geoIpResult - it will give you a close geolocation. I get a place ca 100km away, when using that service on my own ip - so not very precise.